# centering an animation in beamer

Tags: pdftex, vertical-alignment, animate

there's lots about centering in beamer and animation in beamer, but I'm not finding what I need. I have an animation made through R's animate, where I've set the center option TRUE. The resultant tex file successfully compiles into a pdf via pdflatex with only font substitution warnings.

The animation appears in the resultant file and works fine, but it appears at the top of the page, and I want the animation centered top to bottom. It is centered left to right. I've tried \centerline and \hfill, but these seem to work with images not animations.  I've also tried the [c] option in the document declaration line. Any suggestions?
Here's my tex code, not sure how to include the animation itself as it's 3.3 MB.

```
\documentclass[c]{beamer}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\animategraphics[controls,width=\linewidth]{10}{./latex_images/Rplot}{1}  {127}
\end{center}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, even more searching gave me this:

```
\begin{frame}[c,allowframebreaks]

\begin{figure}
.
.
.
\end{figure}

\end{frame}
```

which does the trick.